# Clear Xfce4 session

Tags: xfce, session

How to reset Xfce session?

When I start Xfce4, it always opens 2 windows of Evince, Emacs and one terminal emulator. I remember I used this configuration once a week ago, but now it starts every time after logging in. How can I make Xfce4 start cleanly with no applications?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This question is answered in Xfce wiki, subsection [Some of my applications are always started when I login](http://wiki.xfce.org/faq#some_of_my_applications_are_always_started_when_i_login):

> There are two possible reasons why the application is started: It is saved in the last session or it is listed in the auto started applications. Follow 1 of the two steps below to get rid of the applications.
>
> - Start the xfce4-autostart-editor and remove the application(s). You can also manually delete those files in ~/Desktop/Autostart and ~/.config/autostart.
> - Most of the time closing all the applications and save your session when you logout is sufficient. If this doesn't work, remove the content of the ~/.cache/sessions/ directory when you're not logged in. And if you don't want xfce remember every session you should turn off (uncheck) “Automatically save session on logout” in Settings Manager → Sessions and Startup (tab General)

Run this:

```
rm -fr ~/.cache/sessions/*
```

and Xfce should starts cleanly.

Also, you might need to clear the entire `.cache` directory if the above doesn't fix the issues:

```
rm -fr ~/.cache
```

Comment: You meant `rm -rf ...` right.

Comment: I was able to fix a lot of XFCE4 problems by running `rm -fr ~/.cache`.

Comment: Pay attention that the cache folder may be another folder that ~/.cache it's defined by $XDG_CACHE_HOME

Comment: I would not casually suggest to rm ~/.cache. Lots of other app may depend on subdirs in /cache, so the user may break a lot of things that have nothing to do with the issue.

Answer (score 7):

Using the GUI seems to work as it should, at least in my version of Xfce (4.10).

In Xfce Menu go to 'Session and Startup'

[image]

And there, under Sesion/'Clear saved sessions':

[image]